# Mod rewrite с ума сошел

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Есть файл index.php

```
<?php
require_once "core.php";
require_once THEM."header.php";

  if (isset($_GET['id']))
  {
    if ($_GET['id'] == "contact")
    {
        require "contact.php";
    }
    elseif ($_GET['id'] == "search")
    {
        require "search.php";
    }else{
        require "main.php"; 
    }
  }

require_once THEM."footer.php";
?>
```

Возьмем в пример search.php в котором:

```
<?
require_once LOCALE.LOCALESET."search.php"; # подгружаем что то где LOCALE и LOCALESET это константы которые определены в core.php
echo"Какой то html код";
?>
```

В самом .htaccess есть такое

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule ^search/$ index.php?id=search
```

По ссылке site.com/index.php?id=search все отлично работает грузит файлы:

- core.php
- header.ph
- search.php
- footer.php

А вот если перейти по site.com/search/ то грузит только `search.php` и соответственно ошибка:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(LOCALELOCALESETsearch.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/user/search.php on line 2
```

Comment: Попробуйте распечатать константы LOCALE и LOCALESET сразу после определения, затем в index.php и затем в search.php перед require_once. Чтобы увидеть где константы теряют значение.

Comment: @Alexus такое ощущение что сразу search.php грузит.

Comment: можете привести весь .htaccess ?

Comment: @Alexus да он весь, спецом лишнее все убрали.

Comment: Есть ощущение что RewriteRule перенаправляет без сохранения контекста, т.е. константы, и переменные не определены. Попробуйте перед require search.php определить переменную и распечатать ее значение  в search.php

Comment: @Alexus не передает он переменную. Смотрю и вижу как будто он просто файл на прямую открывает.

Comment: Ради эксперимента, попробуйте изменить имя файла **search.php** на любое другое и сделать все соответствующие изменения в index.php и .htaccess

Comment: @Alexus это и так для теста  сделано, есть целый скрипт с разными файлами и там такие проблемы.  Все идентично страдают от того как будто индекс не участвует

Comment: Я создал два файла  
**index.php**  <?php  
 $ee = 10;  
 echo __FILE__.' ee='.$ee.'<br>';
 if ($_GET['id'] == "search")
    {
  require_once('search.php');
 }
?>И **search.php**  <?php
 echo `__FILE__`.' ee='.$ee.'<br>';
?> Все работает правильно, т.е выводит значение `$ee`

Comment: @Alexus да согласен работает, но не на том сервере где эта проблема. И не понятно почему так происходит.